# Total count filtered by parameters - bash

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

Is there a way to get the total number of lines that filters by certain parameters? For example, I have a log file that contains:

```
COMPLETED: location: DEN brand: A
COMPLETED: location: LHR brand: A
COMPLETED: location: EWR brand: C

COMPLETED: location: DEN brand: A
COMPLETED: location: LHR brand: B
COMPLETED: location: JFK brand: C
```

Is there a way to write the grep command that can return the total number of lines for each location and brand. For example, the command executed would return

```
DEN    A     3
LHR    A     1
LHR    B     1
```

This would have to be dynamic since the locations can be different. So we can't just do something like `grep 'location: DEN' | grep 'brand: A' | wc -l >> file.log`

Any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this also with Bash commands:

```
cat input_file | sed '/^$/d' | sort | uniq -c | sed 's/^ \+//' | cut -d' ' -f1,4,6
```

in this situation output will be as follow:

```
2 DEN A
1 EWR C
1 JFK C
1 LHR A
1 LHR B
```

Comment: Thanks, I had to modify it a little since my log file was slightly different than what I posted (sensitive data reasons), but your solution helped.

Answer (score 0):

***1st solution:*** With GNU `awk` please try following, written and tested with shown samples. Simple explanation would be, setting RS(record separator) to match `DEN brand: A` kind of values in each line. Then using split function to split RS values into arr1 array then creating final array which has values in it to be printed as per shown samples.

```
awk -v RS='[a-zA-Z]+[[:space:]]+brand:[[:space:]]+[a-zA-Z]+' '
RT{
  split(RT,arr1," brand: ")
  arr[arr1[1] OFS arr1[2]]++
}
END{
  for(key in arr){
    print key,arr[key]
  }
}
' Input_file
```

***2nd solution:*** Using `match` function of `awk` here. Simple explanation would be using `match` to match `DEN brand: A` values in line here, then splitting matched values into arr. Finally cnt array which has index as 1st and 2nd value of arr. in END block of `awk` program printing all values of array ant there.

```
awk '
match($0,/[a-zA-Z]+ brand: [a-zA-Z]+/){
  split(substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH),arr," brand: ")
  cnt[arr[1] OFS arr[2]]++
}
END{
  for(key in cnt){
    print key,cnt[key]
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

Comment: @newbie, did my solutions helped you too? Could you please do let me know once, thank you.